# tensorflow no module named example.tutorials.mnist.input_data

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I've installed tensor flow on Mac OS X.
Successfully ran simple command line test.
Now trying the first tutorial.

Fail on the first python line:

[python prompt:] 
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data

But the file seems to be there:

new-host-4:~ karlovitz$ ls /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/
BUILD           fully_connected_feed.py mnist.py        mnist_with_summaries.py
**init**.py     input_data.py       mnist_softmax.py

Comment: This look like a duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

@mkarlovitz Looks like `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` is not in the list of paths python is looking for.

To see what paths are  python uses to find packages, do the below ( you can use command line for this ).
1. `import sys`
2. `sys.path`  ( This tells the list of Paths )

If the  `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`  is not in the above list.
Add it as follows:
In the Python file/script you are executing.
1. `import sys`
2. `sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/')`